# Retroactively stop Excel from interpreting cell values as dates

Tags: excel, datetime, text, number-formatting

I have a series of spreadsheets filled by farmers that list the composition of NPK fertiliser applied to their fields.
In some of these *something* happened with the cell format (that was originally set to text) and now the fertiliser composition is read by Excel as a date.

Example of text entered in the cell (N:P:K):
**25:00:14**

Excel now reads this as:
**01/01/1900  01:00:14**

When looking at the cell, I see the correct value (25:00:14). However, when importing the data into Python, or when copying the value to a different cell, the date (01/01/1900  01:00:14) gets exported instead.

I have tried: changing the cell type to text, copying the contents of the cell into another cell set as text, replacing ':' with a different special character. Nothing along these lines seems to work.

I have a few hundreds of these entries, so any ideas on how to avoid having to re-enter them manually would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may try `=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")` then import/export.

Comment: Nope, that gives `01:00:14`

Comment: `=TEXT(A1,"[hh]:mm:ss")`

Comment: @Sofia Scott is right. Try that one.